# Remove elements from numpy array smaller than 1

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot large data (50 million values) but I am getting a `MemoryError`. Now I am trying to clear my dataset from redundant values. In my case, these are all values below `1` and above `-1`. One thing to keep in mind is that the plot should look the same as the original, but without the noise. Is there a better way to do this than using `loops` or `list comprehensions`?

Original Plot:

[image]

**Edit:**

Thank you for the replies. If I use the proposed approach:

```
daty = daty[(-1 > daty) | (daty > 1)]
```

It results in this:

[image]

Comment: Please share some sample data or `numpy.array` to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your array is named `data`:

```
clipped_data = data[(-1 > data) | (data > 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

A sample I used on imbedded array

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[0, 3], [2, 15], [15, 7], [3, 6]])
e1 = (data[:, 0] < 15)
e2 = (data[:, 1] < 15)

print(data[e1 & e2])
# array([[0, 3], [3, 6]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Numpy allows you to apply a mask to any single dimension of an array, resulting in a subset of the unmasked rows (or data points in your case).

```
data = np.array([1.5, 0.2, -5, -0.5])
mask = np.abs(data) > 1
data = data[mask]
print(data) # output: [1.5, -5]
```

Note that -5 now is at position 1 after the filter.

Comment: makes 2D arrays as 1 D

Comment: @AlexPunnen Unfortunately, there is no other possibility. Let's take a look at niek tuytel example - using 2D array. He is actually applying a rule on a 1D array containing 1D array elements. So the result is a 1D array of 1D array elements - or a 2D array. It is only preserving the rank because it applies the rule along the first dimension, only.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy can do addressing based on an array of booleans, so you can do stuff like this, if you want to set the unwanted values to 0:

```
badIndices = (myArray > 1) | (myArray < -1)
myArray[badIndices]=0
```